# Type Mismatch Error After Executing a Sub that Calls on a Function

Tags: excel, vba

```
Function SetColumn(strMonth As String) As Integer

    If strMonth = "January" Then
    
        SetColumn = 1
        
    ElseIf strMonth = "February" Then
    
        SetColumn = 2
        
    End If

End Function
```

```
Sub ReturnColumn()

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim intColumn As Integer
    Dim strMonth As String
    
    strMonth = ws.Range("A1")
    
    MsgBox "strMonth: " + strMonth
    
    intColumn = SetColumn(strMonth)

    MsgBox "intColumn: " + intColumn

End Sub
```

For some reason, the execution of ReturnColumn() if Range("A1") = January results in a Type Mismatch error instead of 1. I'm not sure if I'm missing something super minor here - the SetColumn function is set as an integer, and intColumn is also set as an integer so there shouldn't be a Type Mismatch as far as I'm concerned.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it definitely the string value "January" in A1, and not a numeric/date value such as 01/01/1900 which is formatted?

Comment: `MsgBox "intColumn: " + intColumn` - it is caused by this line. Concatenating string to int is the reason. Change it to `MsgBox "intColumn: " & intColumn`